# Can I expand the modulus of an encryption scheme?

Tags: public-key, modular-arithmetic

Take the lifted ElGamal as an example: suppose the original ciphertext is $<g^y \bmod q,g^m\bmod q>$. After some calculations, $m$ could be large enough to do modular. But I don't want $m$ to be reduced to a small value. So I was considering whether I can expand the modulus $q$ (e.g., multiply it with another prime $p$), without impacting the correctness of $m$.

Can I use the Chinese Remainder Theorem to achieve this?

Comment: "But I don't want m to be reduced to a small value." Why?